# Calculating no. of pages before the pdf generation

Tags: pdf-generation

I am using ActivePDF tool to convert few different file formats to PDF. Before this conversion, I need to find out how many pages of PDF I will end up with. So, say my word document is converted to 4 page pdf, I need to get that count of pages before the actual conversion.

How can I best achieve this?

Comment: How about doing a trial conversion run, counting the pages of the resulting PDF, then using this number of pages for whatever you need them for and doing the final conversion then?

Comment: So, basically converting them twice? Documents might have even hundreds of pages. Converting twice will suffocate the performance, right?

Comment: Any method trying to determine the number of pages of the result effectively must at least calculate the layout of the result which already does imply reading most of the external resources. So yes, the requirement to know the number of pages beforehand always implies that most of the conversion must be done twice anyways. I'm not sure whether or not ActivePDF includes an explicit method for "calculate the layout and return the number of pages", but even if it does, that method won't be much faster than an actual conversion run.